# How to use the password in pubxml.user during dotnet publish

Tags: asp.net, gitlab-ci, webdeploy

I am trying to setup CI for a ASP.NET project. There is a publish profile defined in VS, which is working fine. (I can deploy the page to a remote IIS server.)

I want to automate this, using GitLab, so I am looking for a command line equivalent of the publish action of VS.

The publish profile files that VS is using can be found under Properties\PublishProfiles. I have 2 files here:

- myServer.pubxml (contains the username to use for deploy, and other server data, like hostname)
- myServer.pubxml.user (contains the encrypted password for the user)

My attempts to deploy/publish on the command line:

`dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=myServer.pubxml`

This results in the following error:

`MSDEPLOY : error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED [C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\Beam Time Request\BeantimeRequest\BeantimeRequest.csproj] Error : The remote server returned an error : (401) Unauthorized. [C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\Beam Time Request\BeantimeRequest\BeantimeRequest.csproj] MSDEPLOY : error count: 1. [C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\Beam Time Request\BeantimeRequest\BeantimeRequest.csproj]`

Which is logical, as I have not defined the password.

I can set the password on the command line, like this:

`dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=myServer.pubxml /p:password=myPassword`

And this works, but I want to avoid having the password written in plain text.

So how could I tell `dotnet publish` to use the password from the myServer.pubxml.user file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone come across this:
I solved this with a GitLab Secret, as follows:

1. Defined a new GitLab Secret for the repository, called DEPLOY_PASSWD
2. using the following command to deploy:
   `dotnet publish -c Release -o Publish /p:PublishProfile=myServer.pubxml /p:password=$DEPLOY_PASSWD"`

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the path or reomve (.pubxml) :

- dotnet publish /p:PublishProfile=myServer /p:password=myPassword